# Summarize grouped rows in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large dataframe like this:

```
t_stamp relaxation  pit
2023-12-19T15:06:35Z    FALSE   -0.038911564
2023-12-19T15:06:51Z    FALSE   -0.037203242
2023-12-19T15:07:03Z    FALSE   -0.035922001
2023-12-19T15:07:19Z    FALSE   -0.034213679
2023-12-19T15:07:35Z    FALSE   -0.032505357
2023-12-19T15:07:46Z    FALSE   -0.031224116
2023-12-19T15:08:06Z    FALSE   -0.029483415
2023-12-19T15:08:14Z    FALSE   -0.029968068
2023-12-19T15:08:34Z    FALSE   -0.030740263
2023-12-19T15:08:46Z    FALSE   0.073617363
2023-12-19T15:09:06Z    TRUE    0.20609313249588013
2023-12-19T15:09:10Z    TRUE    0.21614002653179293
2023-12-19T15:09:33Z    TRUE    0.24940015375614166
2023-12-19T15:09:49Z    TRUE    0.11678649167975427
2023-12-19T15:10:05Z    FALSE   0.008699417
2023-12-19T15:10:17Z    FALSE   0.002999872
2023-12-19T15:10:33Z    FALSE   -0.003341056
2023-12-19T15:10:44Z    FALSE   -0.008096753
2023-12-19T15:11:04Z    FALSE   -0.016022914
```

I would like to calculate the average of values in column "pit" each time the label in column "relaxation" changes. For this snippet, for example, there will be three summary values created: two for the two groups of FALSE values and one for one group of TRUE values.

I tried using the [group_by and summarize](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html) technique from dplyr, but that ends up creating two groups only: one for "pit" values when "relaxation" is FALSE and another for when "relaxation" values are TRUE. I thought about creating another variable to effectively group the values but couldn't find a logical way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

- `cumsum(relaxation != lag(relaxation, default = TRUE))` creates a numeric variable which starts with 1 and increments every time `relaxation` toggles between `TRUE`/`FALSE`, allowing you to detect groups

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_table("t_stamp relaxation  pit
2023-12-19T15:06:35Z    FALSE   -0.038911564
2023-12-19T15:06:51Z    FALSE   -0.037203242
2023-12-19T15:07:03Z    FALSE   -0.035922001
2023-12-19T15:07:19Z    FALSE   -0.034213679
2023-12-19T15:07:35Z    FALSE   -0.032505357
2023-12-19T15:07:46Z    FALSE   -0.031224116
2023-12-19T15:08:06Z    FALSE   -0.029483415
2023-12-19T15:08:14Z    FALSE   -0.029968068
2023-12-19T15:08:34Z    FALSE   -0.030740263
2023-12-19T15:08:46Z    FALSE   0.073617363
2023-12-19T15:09:06Z    TRUE    0.20609313249588013
2023-12-19T15:09:10Z    TRUE    0.21614002653179293
2023-12-19T15:09:33Z    TRUE    0.24940015375614166
2023-12-19T15:09:49Z    TRUE    0.11678649167975427
2023-12-19T15:10:05Z    FALSE   0.008699417
2023-12-19T15:10:17Z    FALSE   0.002999872
2023-12-19T15:10:33Z    FALSE   -0.003341056
2023-12-19T15:10:44Z    FALSE   -0.008096753
2023-12-19T15:11:04Z    FALSE   -0.016022914")

df |> 
  mutate(group = cumsum(relaxation != lag(relaxation, default = TRUE))) |> 
  group_by(group) |> 
  summarise(mean_pit = mean(pit))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   group mean_pit
#>   <int>    <dbl>
#> 1     1 -0.0227 
#> 2     2  0.197  
#> 3     3 -0.00315
```

Comment: You do not need the `mutate` function here, instead use `df %>%group_by(group = cumsum(...))%>%summarise(...)`

Answer (score 3):

**data.table**

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, list(MEAN = mean(pit)), by = rleid(relaxation)]

   rleid         MEAN
1:     1 -0.022655434
2:     2  0.197104951
3:     3 -0.003152287
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `tapply`

```
> tapply(dat$pit, cumsum(c(0, diff(dat$relaxation)) != 0), mean)
           0            1            2 
-0.022655434  0.197104951 -0.003152287
```

Using `ave` you can also have it as a column.

```
> transform(dat, pit_mn=ave(pit, cumsum(c(0, diff(relaxation)) != 0), FUN=mean))
                t_stamp relaxation          pit       pit_mn
1  2023-12-19T15:06:35Z      FALSE -0.038911564 -0.022655434
2  2023-12-19T15:06:51Z      FALSE -0.037203242 -0.022655434
3  2023-12-19T15:07:03Z      FALSE -0.035922001 -0.022655434
4  2023-12-19T15:07:19Z      FALSE -0.034213679 -0.022655434
5  2023-12-19T15:07:35Z      FALSE -0.032505357 -0.022655434
6  2023-12-19T15:07:46Z      FALSE -0.031224116 -0.022655434
7  2023-12-19T15:08:06Z      FALSE -0.029483415 -0.022655434
8  2023-12-19T15:08:14Z      FALSE -0.029968068 -0.022655434
9  2023-12-19T15:08:34Z      FALSE -0.030740263 -0.022655434
10 2023-12-19T15:08:46Z      FALSE  0.073617363 -0.022655434
11 2023-12-19T15:09:06Z       TRUE  0.206093132  0.197104951
12 2023-12-19T15:09:10Z       TRUE  0.216140027  0.197104951
13 2023-12-19T15:09:33Z       TRUE  0.249400154  0.197104951
14 2023-12-19T15:09:49Z       TRUE  0.116786492  0.197104951
15 2023-12-19T15:10:05Z      FALSE  0.008699417 -0.003152287
16 2023-12-19T15:10:17Z      FALSE  0.002999872 -0.003152287
17 2023-12-19T15:10:33Z      FALSE -0.003341056 -0.003152287
18 2023-12-19T15:10:44Z      FALSE -0.008096753 -0.003152287
19 2023-12-19T15:11:04Z      FALSE -0.016022914 -0.003152287
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(t_stamp = c("2023-12-19T15:06:35Z", "2023-12-19T15:06:51Z", 
"2023-12-19T15:07:03Z", "2023-12-19T15:07:19Z", "2023-12-19T15:07:35Z", 
"2023-12-19T15:07:46Z", "2023-12-19T15:08:06Z", "2023-12-19T15:08:14Z", 
"2023-12-19T15:08:34Z", "2023-12-19T15:08:46Z", "2023-12-19T15:09:06Z", 
"2023-12-19T15:09:10Z", "2023-12-19T15:09:33Z", "2023-12-19T15:09:49Z", 
"2023-12-19T15:10:05Z", "2023-12-19T15:10:17Z", "2023-12-19T15:10:33Z", 
"2023-12-19T15:10:44Z", "2023-12-19T15:11:04Z"), relaxation = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), pit = c(-0.038911564, 
-0.037203242, -0.035922001, -0.034213679, -0.032505357, -0.031224116, 
-0.029483415, -0.029968068, -0.030740263, 0.073617363, 0.20609313249588, 
0.216140026531793, 0.249400153756142, 0.116786491679754, 0.008699417, 
0.002999872, -0.003341056, -0.008096753, -0.016022914)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using ifelse and cumsum to create a grouping column.  Then the `group_by()` can be used as mentioned above.

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="t_stamp relaxation  pit
2023-12-19T15:06:35Z    FALSE   -0.038911564
2023-12-19T15:06:51Z    FALSE   -0.037203242
2023-12-19T15:07:03Z    FALSE   -0.035922001
2023-12-19T15:07:19Z    FALSE   -0.034213679
2023-12-19T15:07:35Z    FALSE   -0.032505357
2023-12-19T15:07:46Z    FALSE   -0.031224116
2023-12-19T15:08:06Z    FALSE   -0.029483415
2023-12-19T15:08:14Z    FALSE   -0.029968068
2023-12-19T15:08:34Z    FALSE   -0.030740263
2023-12-19T15:08:46Z    FALSE   0.073617363
2023-12-19T15:09:06Z    TRUE    0.20609313249588013
2023-12-19T15:09:10Z    TRUE    0.21614002653179293
2023-12-19T15:09:33Z    TRUE    0.24940015375614166
2023-12-19T15:09:49Z    TRUE    0.11678649167975427
2023-12-19T15:10:05Z    FALSE   0.008699417
2023-12-19T15:10:17Z    FALSE   0.002999872
2023-12-19T15:10:33Z    FALSE   -0.003341056
2023-12-19T15:10:44Z    FALSE   -0.008096753
2023-12-19T15:11:04Z    FALSE   -0.016022914")
                                                         
library(dplyr)
#define the grouping column
df$groupings = cumsum(ifelse(df$relaxation== lag(df$relaxation, default=1), 0, 1))

#create the summary
df %>% group_by(groupings) %>% summarize(relaxation= first(relaxation), meanvalue= mean(pit))
```